# How can I link different radiobuttons to different folders

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to link different radiobuttons to different folders. I managed to open one folder, but now all the radiobuttons are linked to that folder. I understand that it is because they have the same commend that uses the path of the first radiobutton, but I don't know how to change that. My question is, how can I link different radiobuttons to different folders?
Also, how can I open multiple files from 1 folder at the same time?
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import filedialog 
import tkinter.constants 

class filedialogexample(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.favorite = StringVar()

        tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text = "Browse 1", variable = self.favorite, 
                command = self.askopenfilename
                ).grid( row=2, column =0, columnspan = 2, sticky =W)
        tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text = "Browse 2", variable = self.favorite, 
                command = self.askopenfilename
                ).grid( row=3, column =0, columnspan = 2, sticky =W)
        tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text = "Browse 3", variable = self.favorite,  
                command = self.askopenfilename
                ).grid( row=4, column =0, columnspan = 2, sticky =W)
        tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text = "Browse 4", variable = self.favorite,
                command = self.askopenfilename
                ).grid( row=5, column =0, columnspan = 2, sticky =W)


        self.dir_opt = options = {} 
        options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\Users\\kom01\\Documents\\Python Scripts'


    def askopenfilename(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(**self.dir_opt)
        if filename:
            return open(filename, 'r')

    def askdirectory(self, root):
        return filedialog.askdirectory(**self.dir_opt)

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = Tk()
    filedialogexample(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Do you want the `initialdir` passed to `filedialog.askopenfilename` to be different for each radiobutton?  Anyway, you should give each radiobutton a value so that the variable `self.favorite` will contain the value corresponding to the selected radiobutton. In addition, the file returned by your `askopenfilename` function cannot be used from a button command.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes, every radiobutton has its own `initialdir`. Thanks for the tip on value, forgot that one. Lastly, I found somewhere the code for returning the file by `askopenfilename`, but it doesn't work. What should I use instead?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the file, you can either do it inside the function or you can create an attribute to store the filename, `self.myfile = filename` and use it in an other function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still lost. Could you give me an example in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a different `initialdir` to `filedailog.askopenfilename` depending on which radiobutton is selected, you can use the value option of the radiobutton. Since all your radiobuttons are connected to the `self.favorite` variable, `self.favorite` will contain the value of the selected radiobutton.

First, you need to assign to each radiobutton the path to a folder (`value='path\\to\\folder'` at the radiobutton creation). Then, in `askopenfilename`, you will pass `self.favorite.get()` as `initialdir`. Finally, it's useless to return the opened file, because you cannot get it from the button command. So you should directly perform the operation on the file inside the `askopenfilename` function. In the example below, I just print the content of the file.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog 

class filedialogexample(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.favorite = tkinter.StringVar()

        tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text = "Browse 1", variable = self.favorite, 
                command=self.askopenfilename, value="folder1"
                ).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text = "Browse 2", variable = self.favorite, 
                command=self.askopenfilename, value="folder2"
                ).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text = "Browse 3", variable = self.favorite,  
                command=self.askopenfilename, value="folder3"
                ).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text = "Browse 4", variable = self.favorite,
                command=self.askopenfilename, value="folder4"
                ).grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        # replace folder1,..,folder4 by actual paths to folders


    def askopenfilename(self):
        # initialdir is given by the selected radiobutton
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=self.favorite.get())
        if filename:
            self.do_something_on_selected_file(filename)

    def do_something_on_selected_file(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
            print(myfile.read())

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    filedialogexample(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()
```